# Xarray masking at certain location

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a xarray data set and want to transform the values of my variable in a specific region within the dataset to Nan values. Using dataset.where I only get the specific region as the output but I want to keep the values at the locations around the mask in the array.
So basically I want to keep my dataset but replace the values of my variable at certain coordinates with NaN.

[The dataset is called Lae21 and the lon/lat_mask are sliced coordinates from the dataset]

```
`print(Lae21)
mask = Lae21.where((Lae21.x!=lon_mask) & (Lae21.y!=lat_mask)) 
print(mask)`

    <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (y: 1614, x: 7682)
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) float64 5.261e+06 5.261e+06 5.261e+06 ... 5.256e+06 5.256e+06
  * x        (x) float64 4.389e+05 4.389e+05 4.389e+05 ... 4.619e+05 4.619e+05
Data variables:
    NDVI     (y, x) float32 ...
Attributes:
    transform:            (3.0, 0.0, 438857.72, 0.0, -3.0, 5260962.7)
    crs:                  +init=epsg:32632
    res:                  (3.0, 3.0)
    is_tiled:             0
    nodatavals:           (nan,)
    scales:               (1.0,)
    offsets:              (0.0,)
    AREA_OR_POINT:        Area
    TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION:  1
    TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION:  1
<xarray.DataArray 'NDVI' (y: 3, x: 3)>
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) float64 5.259e+06 5.259e+06 5.259e+06
  * x        (x) float64 4.521e+05 4.521e+05 4.521e+05
```

So the resulting array should be all the values from the original dataset Lae21 and NaN values at the specific location of the mask. (Looking at examples of the .where function I thought that should be the output...).

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `.loc` method for this:

```
Lae21.NDVI.loc[{"x": lat_mask, "y": lon_mask}] = np.NaN
```

See [this specific chapter](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing) of xarray indexing guide for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved it by accessing the region with boolean statements for the coordinates (the coordinates weren't matching with the masks) and xarray.where(mask, np.nan, Lae21['NDVI']...

Comment: Ah! I missed the `!=` in your question. 
Depending on how your `lat_mask` and `lon_mask` shape, you would have two possibilities with `loc` :
1) If they are of the same shape as Lae21.x and Lae21.y `Lae21.NDVI.loc[{"x": ~lat_mask, "y": ~lon_mask}] = np.NaN` 
  2) If they are a subset of x  and y, you need to broadcast them first. The oneliner would then be something like: 
`Lae21.NDVI.loc[{"x": Lae21.NDVI.x != lat_mask.broadcast_like(Lae21.NDVI.x),
 "y": Lae21.NDVI.y != lon_mask.broadcast_like(Lae21.NDVI.y)} ] = np.NaN`

Comment: Thank you, I solved it with boolean statements:

`mask = ((Oen20["x"] > 404252.1938)& (Oen20["x"] < 404258.1938)& (Oen20["y"] > 5237765.319) & (Oen20["y"] < 5237771.3190))

Oen20["NDVI"] = xr.where(mask, np.nan, Oen20["NDVI"])`